# Is there a binary parsing package that is higher level than attoparsec?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to parse a binary file that has a specific structure. I'm currently looking into the "attoparsec" package, but I feel the level is too low for this application.

For example, in order to read in an `Int32` I have to do this:

```
return
    . (fromIntegral :: Word32 -> Int32)
    . runGet getWord32le
    . BS.fromStrict
    =<< A.take 4
```

I think this is way too complicated for just one `Int32`! However, I really like the framework provided by the `parsec`-style parsing, so that I can define the syntax in a style similar the grammar itself.

Is there a higher-level parsing solution for binary files? Ideally it's a package that's based on attoparsec, and has helper functions to read in various types of values, like `Char`, `Int`, `Float`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [**binary**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.6.1/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html) package?

Comment: Yes I have. In fact the `runGet` and `getWord32be` are from that package. I mean it's always possible to parse a file using "binary", but I miss the `many`, `choice`, `*>` and `<|>` etc in "attoparsec", which makes constructing complex parsing logic much more pleasant.

Comment: Now I think about it, maybe I'm asking for too much.

Comment: Do you really need to backtrack? Usually binary formats are designed so you don't have to.